# Length do conteudo retornando valor incorreto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código pra checar se o tamanho da entrada do usuário está de acordo com alguns parâmetros,
mas o tamanho que ele retorna é sempre -1 do tamanho do conteúdo da entrada, seria o caso de converter para int e somar 1?

```js
$("input").keydown(function() {
  console.log($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Tentou keyup ao invés de keydown?

Comment: Era exatamente isso Maurivan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P/ essa verificação utilize o evento `.keyup` ao invés de `.keydown`, visto que o novo caractere só vai ser incluído de fato após o evento `.keyup`. Segue um exemplo funcional retornando o valor correto:

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Ahh agora entendi muito obrigado